# Creating a texview with a resizable custom background

Tags: ios, image, background, textview

Alright, I've been looking for more than a week now, and can't find a solution. I realize there are a lot of questions around about this, but most are about doing this for custom bottoms instead of textviews.

I'm trying to make a textview that uses a custom background image. The issue is, the background image must be a resizable one.

What I'm doing is first setting up the background image:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]
 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

Now, how do I go about adding this image as a background image? Most solutions I found use the  `colorWithPatterImage` method, as follows:

```
 textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
  [UIImage image]];
```

But this doesn't work when you're trying to use a resizable image (this seems to tile the `UImage` you give it, instead of resizing it).

The only other solution I found was adding the image as a subview to the textview, and then using the `sendSubviewToBack` method:

```
[textView addSubview: imgView];
[textView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
[window addSubview: textView];
```

Using this approach started giving me very weird behavior for some reason, though (I can elaborate if needed).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, I do not think it is possible to use a stretchable, UIImage-based UIColor. This is what the docs say:

> You can use pattern colors to set the fill or stroke color just as you would a solid color. During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area.

I just tried adding a stretchable UIImage's CGImage to the UITextView's CALayer, but that doesn't seem to help.

I think that you'll have to resort to some view beneath the text view that matches the frame and border radius or you could subclass UIColor, create a new initializer, and override the `setFill` method.

Comment: Setting the background using a different view never crossed my mind. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I can't believe I wasted this much time when the solution was this simple. That was a lifesaver, thank you very much!